# How do I run x86 software on arm arch

Tags: 18.04, arm

I have arm architecture and I want to install a x86 program. it is an executable so i ran chmod and did all of that and it said unable to execute binary file. exec format error. can anyone help. thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: hi Pilot thanks for the quick answer is there any software i can use to run it

Comment: To run what????

Comment: it is a game from itch.io it is called aground is it possible to run it on arm

Comment: If there is no executable for arm, you can't run it on arm.